Translate Excel Formula into Power Query
I would like to add a column with "Account No" in the General Ledger extracted from Yardi. Please see an example screenshot below:

Essentially, I need to fill in the column "Account No" with the values in column A that start with "11" for each row that has data. In the example screenshot, this would be only in rows 19 and 20.
I accomplished this with an Excel formula in column "L":
=IF(ISBLANK(B19);"";IF(ISNUMBER(LEFT(L18;1)*1);L18;A18))

I would need to translate this formula (or equivalent) into a Power Query custom column, but I have not idea how to do that.
Can you please help me with this?

Since you chose to provide only a screen shot, and not text which could be easily copy/pasted, my solution uses only the relevant columns.
You will need to adapt the code to include your other columns.
Algorithm:

Group by the Property rows that start with "1" using the optional fourth and fifth arguments of the Table.Group function.
Then apply your formula algorithm to each subgroup

Source Data:

M-Code from Advanced Editor
Edit: Code altered to test that Property starts with any digit
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Property", type text}, {"Property Name", type text}, {"Account No", type any}}),

    x = Text.StartsWith("1!","1"),
    
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Property"}, {
        {"AcctNum", (t)=>Table.ReplaceValue(
            t,
            each [Property Name],
            t[Property]{0},
            (x,y,z)=> if y=null then null
                        else if x <>null then x
                        else z,
            {"Account No"}), 
            type table [Property=nullable text, Property Name=nullable text, Account No=nullable text]}},
         GroupKind.Local,(x,y)=>Number.From(
             List.Contains({"0".."9"}, Text.Start(x[Property],1)) and 
             List.Contains({"0".."9"}, Text.Start(y[Property],1)))),
    
    
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Property"}),
    
    #"Expanded AcctNum" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "AcctNum", {"Property","Property Name", "Account No"})
in 
    #"Expanded AcctNum"

Result:


Thank you for your answer! Your solution works perfectly, I just needed to adjust the code to include the other columns, as you mentioned. My dataset has more than 250k rows, and the accounts start also with other numbers. How can the code be adjusted to include those as well? So, instead of grouping by just the rows that start with "1", I should group by the rows that start with any number (0..9).

@Damcif It's just a matter of changing the fifth argument of the Table.Group function. See my edited code.

Perfect, thanks!

@Damcif Glad to help. Since my answer seems to be what you require, kindly mark it as Accepted.  See What should I do when someone answers my question.

let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table4"]}[Content],
    ChangeType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Property", type text}, {"Property Name", type text}}),
    AddCustom = Table.AddColumn(ChangeType, "Filled Property", each [Property]),
    FillDown = Table.FillDown(AddCustom, {"Filled Property"}),
    ClearFilledProperty = Table.ReplaceValue(
        FillDown, 
        each [Filled Property], 
        each if [Property Name] = null then null else [Filled Property], 
        Replacer.ReplaceValue, 
        {"Filled Property"}
    )

in 

    ClearFilledProperty


Thanks a lot for your answer! I tried the code but I couldn't get the result I needed. The "Filled Property" column doesn't show the account numbers but the property names.
